# Writing a prepared statement to retrieve data from table (fatal error)

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table called candidates with some fields. The table contains a column named "keypass" which is the same for all users and is set as default. Using prepared statement I'm trying to first capture the value for key pass (which is the same for this example) and compare it to the user input.

the connection

```
<?php 
$dbServerName = "localhost"; 
$dbUserName = "root"; 
$dbPassword = ""; 
$dbName = "candidateDB"; 
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServerName,$dbUserName,$dbPassword,$dbName‌​);
```

here is my code:

```
$stm_keypass = $conn ->prepare ("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE keypass = ?");
$stm_keypass -> bind_param("s", $keypass);
$sql_keypass = $stm_keypass->execute();
```

when I run the script I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" what is the issue? thanks

[table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkiV0.jpg)

Comment: @RiggsFolly mysqli

Comment: @RiggsFolly  no its just an empty variable. I'm basing mine on this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @RiggsFolly so how would you get that value from the table?

Comment: Since you're using the object-oriented interface for all of your calls, which is the recommended way to do it, the connection statement should look like `new mysqli($dbServerName, ...)` to make it consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" here would mean your `$stm_keypass` was likely not created properly, and is thus not an object. Check out the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) on how to handle error detection of prepared statements and go from there.